# Browserify Babel ES2015 Knockout co-dependent modules

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I have created a set of singleton modules which get loaded various knockout components and provide a central "command and control" for their respective functional areas.  Let's call them FooModule and BarModule

So a typical Knockout component will have

```
const ko = require('knockout'),
    FooModule =require('../Singletons/FooModel'),
    BarModule =require('../Singletons/BarModel');
```

This seems to work well, with each module supporting various observables and functions

The problem is, I need FooModel to require BarModel, and BarModel to require FooModel.

This probably wouldn't matter if it was not a Singleton (e.g. Class), however I can't have a separate class per module per component or I would lose the ability to communicate across the components (each page typically has 3-7 components, some of which are duplicates but with different data)

Currently FooModel requires BarModel and vice versa, but the resultant object is {}, which presumably how Browserify deals with files that require each other

Currently each singleton module equates to:

```
FooModel...
    const ko = require('knockout');
    const BarModel = require('./BarModel');
    let hiddenVariable = 42 ;
    const FooModel = {
       FooMonitor : ko.observable(false),
       FooFunction : (variable) => { functionFoo(variable) }
    }
    const functionFoo = (variable) => {
        return variable === hiddenVariable ;
    };
    module.export FooModel ;


BarModel...
    const ko = require('knockout');
    const FooModel = require('./FooModel');
    let hiddenVariable = 24 ;
    const BarModel = {
       BarMonitor : ko.observable(false),
       BarFunction : (variable) => { functionBar(variable) }
    }
    const functionBar = (variable) => {
        return variable === hiddenVariable ;
    };
    module.export BarModel ;
```

Each Knockout component happily requires FooModel & BarModel, but if I add

```
console.info(BarModel)
```

In the FooModel Module the browser gets `{}` (empty object)

Comment: ps - in BarModel, FooModel is required OK. It's just in FooModel that I cannot load BarModel.  BarModel runs first (presumably because it's a dependency on FooModel, which by default would get loaded first)

Comment: Generally, when you discover a circular dependency in your code, it's a sign that your architecture has gone wrong. You can escape from such dependencies by using decoupling techniques such as events instead of a hardwiring the dependency.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26445828/browserify-require-returns-an-empty-object

Comment: I can use KO.postbox between Foo & Bar - there isn't a lot of chatter now that each KO component has access to the new models. I think there is a valid place for co-dependence, but this probably isn't it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `FooModel` requires `BarModel`, `BarModel` can't requires `FooModel`. It is a module bundler limitation.

Browserify will automatically remove not-used dependencies. That's why the module output is only stripped to `{}` when you start using BarModel from FooModel.

Incorporating comments from @spender - when you discover circular dependencies it is time to change the architecture.  Events are a good way to decouple the models (in this case, using KO.postbox will work fine).

Comment: PS: I wish I could find the relevant documentation bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a controlling module that requires both Foo and Bar. Then you can initialize Foo by passing in Bar, and initialize Bar by passing in Foo.

Comment: This is not a wrong answer. I am trying to just load the required dependencies only when needed (but when Foo is required, so is Bar and Bas), so will go with backend events coordination (before the refactor, each KO component had between 4 and 11 ko postboxes)